# Two nots in CSS selector with Nokogiri

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

Right now I have a selector working with jQuery as follows:

```
.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"],.retweeted)
```

However this doesn't seem to work using the Nokogiri gem in ruby:

```
doc.css('.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"],.retweeted)')
```

The above causes a cash, but each of the parts of the not independently work:

```
 doc.css('.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"])')
```

and

```
 doc.css('.original-tweet:not(.retweeted)')
```

What's the best way to actually get the selector I want. Is this something that just isn't supported in nokogiri?

Comment: Worth noting that Nokogiri does not support many jQuery CSS query extensions, though this is on the roadmap for Nokogiri 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved it with XPATH

The following worked (note: the xpath I created was entirely computer generated)

```
doc.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' original-tweet ') and not(@data-is-reply-to = \"true\") and not(@data-retweet-id)]")
```

Edit: further inspection shows that this is still selecting items with the retweeted class (turns out this was a false assumption on my part, I should have been looking for the data-retweet-id attribute instead of the retweet class)

github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/451 - this issue relates to why I needed to use xpath here.

Comment: So is it solved with your current XPath? I can't tell from your edit if you fixed it.

Comment: It is based on the original assumption, so I am keeping it rather than updating my question to be more valid.

Answer (score 1):

While the selector may work with jQuery, it's not a valid CSS selector:

```
> $$('.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"], .retweeted)')
Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
```

`.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"]):not(.retweeted)` should work.

Comment: Sadly, nokogiri still chokes and dies on that

Comment: @LindseyB: What's the traceback?

Comment: `parser_extras.rb:87:in on_error: unexpected ':not(' after '[#@type=:CONDITIONAL_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node: @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["*"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node: @type=:COMBINATOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f864e13b380 @type=:CLASS_CONDITION, @value=["original-tweet"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f864e148b70 @type=:NOT, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f864e148f30 @type=:ATTRIBUTE_CONDITION, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x007f864e149480 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["data-is-reply-to"]>, :equal, "\"true\""]>]>]>]>]' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)`

Comment: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/451 turns out there's a ticket open for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For now a possible workaround might be:

```
doc.css('.original-tweet:not([data-is-reply-to="true"])') - doc.css('.retweeted')
```